# VBA - Extract form fields from a word doc that has been saved as a pdf

Tags: vba, excel, pdf, ms-word

My company has a word document form that is filled in by customers containing their feedback on our service.

Data from these forms are extracted from the word document and dumped into excel using the following VBA...this works fine.

```
Dim Val As String
Dim WrdDoc As Document
Dim FormFieldCounter As Integer
Dim TotalFormFields As Integer

Set wordapp = CreateObject("word.Application")
wordapp.Documents.Open filename:=filenme, ReadOnly:=True
wordapp.ScreenUpdating = False

Set WrdDoc = wordapp.Documents(filenme)
wordapp.Visible = True

Dim version As String
version = WrdDoc.Sections(1).Footers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary).Range.Text

FormFieldCounter = 1

RowCounter = RowCounter + 1

TotalFormFields = WrdDoc.FormFields.Count

Do While FormFieldCounter <= TotalFormFields

    WrdDoc.FormFields(FormFieldCounter).Select
    Val = WrdDoc.FormFields(FormFieldCounter).result
    Sheets("Sheet 1").Cells(RowCounter, FormFieldCounter) = Val

    FormFieldCounter = FormFieldCounter + 1

Loop

wordapp.Documents(filenme).Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
wordapp.Quit
```

Quite a lot of the time customers return the MS-Word feedback forms saved as PDFs and the above method obviously doesnt work for these.

As the customers have created these PDF files themselves and it is a not a form created in Adobe Acrobat, I don't know which method to use to extract the data or know if it is even possible.

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Ask your customers not to save as pdf.

Comment: Hahaha, I knew someone would say that! We have tried that and unfortunately it doesnt work for either us or the customers. 

We receive about 50 feedback forms a day and having to go back to each customer is very time consuming, I would like the tool to be able to handle it.

And before someone else says, changing the form to a PDF is not something we can do either!

Comment: PDF from VBA is... I once wrote a PDF Extracter in VB6. It worked OK but I would not want to work with that for such a purpose. Would you consider switching to `.Net Office.Interop`? You could use `Docotic.Pdf`library to parse the PDF for what you need. Not sure how good that would work though. I could give this a try beforehand. What kind of form fields are you using? Word 2010 or older form fields? Text boxes only or also dropdowns, checkboxes, etc.?

Comment: Argh. Forget Docotic. Too expensive. I'll try FreeSpire.

Comment: Have you tried opening the PDF files in Word 2013 or 2016? Those versions can open PDF and convert to a Word format. Whether it would be a format you can use effectively is another question, but at least you'd have "unlocked" the content.

Comment: @CindyMeister Now that is interesting. Didn't know that. Might be the best way. Since the PDF were created from Word documents they should be of relatively good quality - unless they're printed and scanned of course.

Comment: @CindyMeister thanks for the suggestion, that would be great but unfortunately we are on Word 2010 and I can't see us upgrading anytime soon.